# how to solve "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:50765/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

i am trying to add date picker to my textbox. i have added all needed java scripts and referenced it properly but it is giving me following error.

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http:/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"

Comment: Please show your JS included code.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
});
function onSubmit() {
var empId = document.getElementById('EmpId');
var deptid = document.getElementsById('DeptId');
if (empId.value.trim() == 0 || isNaN(parseInt(empId.value))) {
empId.value = '0';
}
}
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to include jQuery:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem will occur if jquery-1.5.1 is missing from script folder. Check the path for file `jquery-1.5.1.min.js`. If it's a webapp you are running, it would be placed inside `<webapp-root>/Scripts`. Also, as per the error it seems that you have come one extra directory back while setting the path for this file.

`NuGet` package to be installed using command - `Install-Package jQuery -Version 1.5.1` as specified on [this link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery/1.5.1).

Comment: cant his problem occur if jquery-1.5.1 is missing from script folder. if yes which Nuget package should i install to solve it?

Comment: Is it fine to install upper version of jQuery? will it contain all files that are need by lower version of jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line before `<html>` tag

`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>`

Then, put this code in your HTML `<head></head>`

`<script src='<c:url value="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"/>'></script>`